# KeyError 'res.user' when starting tryton client

Tags: python, tryton

**Environment:**
MAC High Sierra running Tryton 3.8 TCP/IP

When starting Tryton client, I get the following traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/site-packages/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 162, in
>   _marshaled_dispatch
>       response['result'] = dispatch_method(method, params)   File "/site-packages/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 191, in _dispatch
>       res = dispatch(*args)   File "/site-packages/trytond/protocols/dispatcher.py", line 41, in dispatch
>       res = security.login(database_name, user, session)   File "/site-packages/trytond/security.py", line 25, in login
>       User = pool.get('res.user')   File "/site-packages/trytond/pool.py", line 172, in get
>       return self._pool[self.database_name][type][name] KeyError: 'res.user'

`trytond.conf` contents:

```
#
# This file contains the most common settings for trytond (Defaults
# are commented).
# For more information read 
# /us`enter code here`r/share/doc/packages/trytond

[database]
# Database related settings

# The URI to connect to the SQL database (following RFC-3986)
# uri = database://username:password@host:port/
# (Internal default: sqlite:// (i.e. a local SQLite database))
#
# PostgreSQL via Unix domain sockets
# (e.g. PostgreSQL database running on the same machine (localhost))
#

#Default setting for a local postgres database

#uri = postgresql:///

#
# PostgreSQL via TCP/IP
# (e.g. connecting to a PostgreSQL database running on a remote machine or
# by means of md5 authentication. Needs PostgreSQL to be configured to accept
# those connections (pg_hba.conf).)
uri=postgresql://jcnorman:29Nov1991@localhost:5432

# The path to the directory where the Tryton Server stores files.
# The server must have write permissions to this directory.
# (Internal default: /var/lib/trytond)
path = /var/lib/tryton

# Shall available databases be listed in the client?
#list = True

# The number of retries of the Tryton Server when there are errors 
# in a request to the database
#retry = 5

# The primary language, that is used to store entries in translatable
# fields into the database.
#language = en_US

[ssl]
# SSL settings
# Activation of SSL for all available protocols.
# Uncomment the following settings for key and certificate
# to enable SSL.

# The path to the private key
#privatekey = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

# The path to the certificate
#certificate = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem

[jsonrpc]
# Settings for the JSON-RPC network interface

# The IP/host and port number of the interface
# (Internal default: localhost:8000)
#
# Listen on all interfaces (IPv4)

listen = 0.0.0.0:8000

#
# Listen on all interfaces (IPv4 and IPv6)
#listen = [::]:8000

# The hostname for this interface
#hostname = 

# The root path to retrieve data for GET requests
#data = jsondata

[xmlrpc]
# Settings for the XML-RPC network interface

# The IP/host and port number of the interface
#listen = localhost:8069

[webdav]
# Settings for the WebDAV network interface

# The IP/host and port number of the interface
#listen = localhost:8080

[session]
# Session settings

# The time (in seconds) until an inactive session expires
#timeout = 3600

# The server administration password used by the client for
# the execution of database management tasks. It is encrypted
# using using the Unix crypt(3) routine. A password can be
# generated using the following command line (on one line):
# $ python -c 'import getpass,crypt,random,string; \
# print crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(), \
# "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 8)))'
# Example password with 'admin'
super_pwd = jkUbZGvFNeugk

[email]
# Mail settings

# The URI to connect to the SMTP server.
# Available protocols are:
# - smtp: simple SMTP
# - smtp+tls: SMTP with STARTTLS
# - smtps: SMTP with SSL
#uri = smtp://localhost:25

# The From address used by the Tryton Server to send emails.
#from = tryton@localhost

[report]
# Report settings

# Unoconv parameters for connection to the unoconv service.
#unoconv = pipe,name=trytond;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext

# Module settings
#
# Some modules are reading configuration parameters from this
# configuration file. These settings only apply when those modules
# are installed.
#
#[ldap_authentication]
# The URI to connect to the LDAP server.
#uri = ldap://host:port/dn?attributes?scope?filter?extensions
# A basic default URL could look like
#uri = ldap://localhost:389/

[web]
# Path for the web-frontend
#root = /usr/lib/node-modules/tryton-sao
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialized the database like the documentation explain: http://doc.tryton.org/4.6/trytond/doc/topics/setup_database.html#topics-setup-database

```
trytond-admin -c <config file> -d <database name> --all
```

Comment: Did you notice I'm running Tryton 3.8?   I was hesitant to move to Tryton V4, but after some further research, I think I'll try that approach.  I'll let you know what I encounter.

Comment: I tried uninstalling 3.8, installing latest, and get the following (showing from install:

Comment: I tried uninstalling 3.8, installing latest, and get the following: <br/> 

trytond-admin -c ~/bryants/trytond.conf -d steve --all
Traceback (most recent call last):
(Ignore prior commment) <br/>  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/trytond-admin", line 21, in <module>
    admin.run(options) . . . intermediate messages removed for length <br/>
trytond.exceptions.MissingDependenciesException: Missing dependencies: webdav

Comment: After doing pip install trytond_webdav, now I get:  

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trytond/modules/currency/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .currency import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trytond/modules/currency/currency.py", line 6, in <module>
    from trytond.tools import safe_eval, datetime_strftime
ImportError: cannot import name safe_eval

Comment: I see the problem - I'm using an old version of Currency.